# Converting Youtube Player API to Plyr.io

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, vimeo, plyr.js

I have a codepen which is a video slider built with the Youtube Player API.

It seems like the only functions that would need converting is the
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()

and the line:

```js
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
```

Can anyone help convert it to work with the Plyr API?

Any feedback is appreciated

https://codepen.io/MendleMeyer/pen/NEQoRw?editors=1010

Plyr Docs:
https://github.com/sampotts/plyr